# Javascript tooltip library: prevent wrong elements from displaying tooltip

Tags: javascript, function, attributes, static-libraries, document

I have found a tooltip library that I'm trying to adapt to my needs. I thought I was nearly finished but alas: big fat bug.

So it's supposed to work as any regular tooltip (which it does). Unfortunately it applies an empty tooltip to any element on the page, instead of only to the ones that have a data attribute.

So to work the tooltip needs a data-type attribute set to tooltip and a template:

```
<button data-type="tooltip" data-title-template-id="test">This is supposed to have a tooltip.</button>
```

At the moment it displays a tooltip regardless of dataattributes.

It becomes rather clear in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/El4a/0t19bbeh/

I know the problem is that it always appends a child to the target element (even one with empty text and this causes the issue) I just cant figure out how to prevent this =(

I'm completely aware I'm doing stuff wrong with passing parameters or scope or whatnot, I just don't know what's the right way.

Comment: see line 23 in this [update](https://jsfiddle.net/0t19bbeh/3/) fiddle - looks to fix the issue

Comment: sweet heavens that was easy enough! thank you very much. I don't really understand why though.

Comment: because that function is called on any hover event

Comment: oh the solution isn''t complete! when the data-title-template-id attribute is present, it still displays (even though data-type is missing) as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/El4a/0t19bbeh/4/

Comment: well, why would you do that?

Comment: because the final idea is that you can have data-type="tooltip", data-type="typeahead", data-type="whatever", so it's important to know which one they want.

Comment: well, just put some logic in there to check

Answer (score 0):

You should change `data-type` properties to `data-toggle` ones.

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-title-template-id="test">This is supposed to have a tooltip.</button>

<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="test">This is supposed to have a tooltip.</button>
```

After try it maybe it will be helpful for you and also can change with title....